# PulseAudio recording and playback fails

Tags: c, linux, centos, pulseaudio

I am trying to record and playback audio data using pulse audio API in centOS 6.2. But it records and playbacks nothing. I am using a code from [pulseaudio](http://jan.newmarch.name/LinuxSound/Sampled/PulseAudio/). I need help to get it working in my PC. What should I do? My code is also given below-

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <pulse/simple.h>
#include <pulse/error.h>

#define BUFSIZE 32

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

/* The Sample format to use */
static const pa_sample_spec ss = {
    .format = PA_SAMPLE_S16LE,
    .rate = 44100,
    .channels = 2
};

pa_simple *s_in, *s_out = NULL;
int ret = 1;
int error;


/* Create a new playback stream */
if (!(s_out = pa_simple_new(NULL, argv[0], PA_STREAM_PLAYBACK, NULL, "playback", &ss, NULL, NULL, &error))) {
    fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_new() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
    goto finish;
}

  if (!(s_in = pa_simple_new(NULL, argv[0], PA_STREAM_RECORD, NULL, "record", &ss, NULL, NULL, &error))) {
    fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_new() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
    goto finish;
}

for (;;) {
    uint8_t buf[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t r;

#if 1
    pa_usec_t latency;

    if ((latency = pa_simple_get_latency(s_in, &error)) == (pa_usec_t) -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_get_latency() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
        goto finish;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "In:  %0.0f usec    \r\n", (float)latency);

    if ((latency = pa_simple_get_latency(s_out, &error)) == (pa_usec_t) -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_get_latency() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
        goto finish;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Out: %0.0f usec    \r\n", (float)latency);
#endif

    if (pa_simple_read(s_in, buf, sizeof(buf), &error) < 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": read() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        goto finish;
    }

    /* ... and play it */
    if (pa_simple_write(s_out, buf, sizeof(buf), &error) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_write() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
        goto finish;
    }
}

/* Make sure that every single sample was played */
if (pa_simple_drain(s_out, &error) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, __FILE__": pa_simple_drain() failed: %s\n", pa_strerror(error));
    goto finish;
}

ret = 0;

finish:

if (s_in)
    pa_simple_free(s_in);
if (s_out)
    pa_simple_free(s_out);

return ret;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far to debug it, how far did it get and what did you find?

Comment: its just prints latency but does not playback any sound.

Comment: Please don't use `goto`s.

Comment: @David ths code was taken from the example file from pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully done. It was an error in my OS, because I haven't updated the plugins for a while. After re-installing the OS it worked.
Thanks